# Custom shaped WPF control

Tags: wpf

I'm searching for a way to create a WPF Control with custom shape which will be able to contain child controls.

Simplifying the question, I need something like a non-rectangular panel.

**UPDATE:**
I need a "real" custom shape. Not to capture mouse events outside the shape and so on.

Comment: WPF controls take the shape of their contents -- if your control just contains an Ellipse, then it's ellipse-shaped. It won't respond to mouse clicks outside that ellipse. So just make a background that's the shape you want, and then put stuff on top of it.

Comment: @adonz why can't you use the outer bounds of your control keeping the control's bacground as null? Null will your control transparent for the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would derive from ContentControl, and then as child in it i would put a content presenter, in the content presenter you can put any panel such as a canvas in which you can host other elements. I would do this as a Template applied to your control and would bind the content of the presenter to the content property of the control, in such a way adding to the content property of your control will add it to the presenter which will show it. Here is an example:

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="MyCustomControl">
                <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="myEllipse Background="Green"/> <!-- the control won't catch events outside it-->
                </Grid>
 </ControlTemplate>
```

Then just apply the template to your control and you are all set, don't forget to add a panel as the child to content if you want to host other elements in it.

Comment: Actually, I did not get how to make everything custom shaped. P.S. See my update.

Comment: It won't capture outside the shape, if you want to contain child elements than you have to do it this way. If you want a custom shape outside the content presenter, just add it in the grid. It won't capture mouse wants outside the shape, and the control will take the shahpe of the shape provided. If you try it you'll see it works. If you want to make a custom shape you can inherit from shape and override the defining geometry property. See the updated code above for a custom shape in the tempalte.